# Group by month using cell above filtered cells

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I have a spreadsheet that looks like this:

[image: Spreadsheet Example]

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1b29gyEgCDwor_KJ6ACP2rxdvauOzacDI9FL2K-jgg5E/edit?usp=sharing

I have two columns I'm interested in, Date and Count. Every few dates, there will be a "TOTAL" line where all the Counts corresponding to that TOTAL will be summed. 
I want an output that looks like the cells to the right, where all the TOTAL counts are summed according to month. The problem lies in that Column A has only the date or TOTAL, in separate rows, and this layout can't be changed, leaving me thinking I need to reference *the cell directly above* TOTAL in column A, which has the correct month I want to group that TOTAL by.

The reason why I can't just filter column A by date range is because of inconsistent use, where sometimes the count data is only entered in the TOTAL row.

I've scoured the internet exploring FILTER, INDIRECT, QUERY, SUMIFS, etc... but can't find exactly how to do this.

I can easily filter column B where A:A="TOTAL", but what I think I am needing to do after that is use each cell *above* where A:A="TOTAL" as a range for the month criteria, somehow using what I found here: https://exceljet.net/formula/sum-by-month, expressed by ">="&D3 and "<="&EOMONTH(D3,0).

Any help or alternatives would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Done! Please see the link added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

or a different (offset) approach:

```
=QUERY(FILTER({EOMONTH(INDIRECT("A1:A"&ROWS(B2:B)), 0), B2:B}, A2:A="total"),
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) 
  group by Col1 
  label sum(Col2)'' 
  format Col1'mmmm'", 0)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: This works! Would I add "order by Col1 desc" into the query to have the latest month appear at the top?

Comment: @Leanna yes, go for it

Comment: Using the following gives me an error: =QUERY(FILTER({EOMONTH(INDIRECT("A1:A"&ROWS(C2:C)), 0), C2:C}, A2:A="total"),
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) 
  group by Col1 
  label sum(Col2) ' ' 
  format Col1'mmmm' 
  order by Col1 desc", 0)      Is the order of this part important maybe?

Comment: @Leanna yes, order of parameters matters. use: `=QUERY(FILTER({EOMONTH(INDIRECT("A1:A"&ROWS(B2:B)), 0), C2:C}, A2:A="total"),
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) 
  group by Col1 
  order by Col1 desc
  label sum(Col2)'' 
  format Col1'mmmm'", 0)`

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks for the reference.

Comment: Since I've made it this far, do you know if it's possible to query 2 or more sheets like this? For ex, if the current sheet is 2019, I also have a sheet for 2018 and want to display a query for both with no breaks in between. My guess after experimenting with a few approaches: `=QUERY({FILTER({EOMONTH(INDIRECT("'2019'!A1:A"&ROWS('2019'!B2:B)), 0), '2019'!B2:B}, '2019'!A2:A="total")&FILTER({EOMONTH(INDIRECT("'2018'!A1:A"&ROWS('2018'!B2:B)), 0), '2018'!B2:B}, '2018'!A2:A="total")},          "select Col1,sum(Col2) group by Col1 order by Col1 desc label sum(Col2)'' format Col1'mmmm'", 0)`

Comment: you mean like summary of both sheets?

Answer (score 0):

Query formula is great for these kind of situations but looking at it by month will introduce issues if you plan on looking at multi-year data:

```
=arrayformula(QUERY(QUERY({row(A:A),TEXT(A:A,"MMMM"),B:B},"SELECT max(Col1),Col2,sum(Col3) where Col3 is not null group by Col2 order by max(Col1) label Col2 'Month', sum(Col3) 'Count'"),"SELECT Col2,Col3"))
```

Comment: This works to sum all the counts in column B for which column A isn't "TOTAL". But, what I need is to sum the counts in column B for each TOTAL line. Then, I need to group them by month. That's because sometimes only the TOTAL row will have the count I need. Please see my edited figure adding a visual for this scenario.

Comment: @Leanna it doesn't appear that you have a coherent pattern, you have multiple totals for January, how does that make any sense, what is preventing the total column from using a combination of two different months unexpectedly?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({IF((B2:B="")*(A2:A=""),,VLOOKUP(ROW(A2:A), 
 IF(A2:A<>"total", {ROW(A2:A), DATEVALUE("01/"&MONTH(A2:A)&"/2000")}), 2, 1)), 
 IF(A2:A= "total", A2:A, ), B2:B}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col3) 
  where lower(Col2) = 'total' 
  group by Col1 
  label sum(Col3)'' 
  format Col1'mmmm'", 0))
```

[image: 0]